# SQL Server XML query: how to select values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

How to select file names from xml like this, i.e.
I need only names:

```
c:\temp\f1.txt
c:\temp\f2.txt
```

XML like this:

```
<root name="name" id="12">
<class1>
     <file name="c:\temp\f1.txt">
</class1>
<class1>
   <subclass1>
        <file name="c:\temp\f2.txt">
    </subclass1>
</class1>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
declare @XML xml 
set @XML = '
<root name="name" id="12">
  <class1>
       <file name="c:\temp\f1.txt"/>
  </class1>
  <class1>
     <subclass1>
          <file name="c:\temp\f2.txt"/>
      </subclass1>
  </class1>
</root>'

select T.N.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)') as FileName
from @XML.nodes('//file') as T(N)
```